# Get non-HTML data from an IFRAME with javascript

Tags: html, css, ajax, json, iframe

I have a situation in which a hidden IFRAME loads a page.  The page does not return HTML data but rather a raw JSON string.  Since the data is not HTML there is no "body" tag and I can not use the following suggestion that was given in another SO question:

```
  iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

The content of the IFRAME is similar to:

```
   IFRAME:
   -----------------------------------------------
   |     {"JSON" : "HERE" }                       |
   -----------------------------------------------

   and not

   ------------------------------------------------
   |       <html>                                 |
   |            <body>                            |
   |                 {"JSON" : "HERE" }           |
   |            </body>                           |
   |       </html>                                |
   ------------------------------------------------
```

I'm basically asking how to get the raw contents of an iFrame.  Adding pseudo HTML tags is not an option.  Not using an iFrame is not an option.  Thanks!

Comment: is your iframe on the same domain as your main page ?

Comment: yes it is.  I have an onLoad event for the IFRAME so if I could get the entire pages html from inside that would work too.  I could do parent.processFrame(document.getElementById(????).innerHTML);, but once again I run into the fact that there are no html tags.  If I could somehow do a document.getRawPage() that would work but no such function exists.

Comment: you mentioned you had to use and iframe, why is this why would you not just run a ajax get on the page ?

Comment: Support for very old devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get iframe response headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250103/how-to-get-iframe-response-headers)