# How to get iframe response headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Is there a way to get response headers of an iframe onload?

I have already googled it, but really I could not find something useful about it!

Comment: You need to make an ajax request to your iframe url, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Not really. If the iframe is on the same domain you can access its document object which contains some useful information such as `document.referrer`, but you cannot intercept the full HTTP headers without making an Ajax request for the URL. This would mean requesting the URL again. e.g:

```
$.ajax( { url: $(#myFrame).attr('src'), success: function(r,x){
    console.log( x.getResponseHeader('SomeHeader') );
} } );
```

This will only work if the iframe src is in the same domain as the calling script.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that you cannot call the page again. And if you do so, you will receive an error that says `not available`.

Comment: You're doing something unconventional. Expect blockers.

Comment: I don't know what you did at all.

Comment: What is so unconventional about doing a non-repeatable multi-part POST?

Answer (score -1):

If you have control on the loaded iframe resource you can dump the header content on a postMessage request to the main window.

Comment: To do that the JavaScript inside the page loaded into the frame would have to read the headers which, as was pointed out [amost a decade ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17250188/19068) isn't possible.

Comment: You can hard-print all headers as javascript if you have PHP enabled.