# Accessing response headers of an iframe in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have an `iframe` in my `JQuery` code like this:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe height="500px">');
        iframe.attr('src', 'someUrl');
```

which I execute within a function after a condition is met, and it is working as expected. In the `url` I am also generating and adding some headers to the response which I can see in the `network` tab of `chrome`. I would like to access those headers if possible (`AJAX` call is not an option as this url produces pdf which I am displaying in an `iframe` within a `div`). By following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header) I tried:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe height="500px">');
        iframe.attr('src', 'someUrl');
console.log(iframe.contents().find("someHeader").html());
```

which results in `undefined`. How can I access those response headers which I can see in the browser's inspection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250103/how-to-get-iframe-response-headers may help.

Comment: Ajax would be only way.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, unfortunately with ajax i cannot display the pdf in a div, or can i?

Comment: But you can make a different ajax HEAD request to get the headers. Not sure why you are doing this , seems strange to me

Comment: @charlietfl I have to use iframe because the controller I am calling with the iframe is producing pdf which I am only allowed to display in a div. The controller is also doing some checks with the produced pdf file and adding headers to inform the browser whether the checks failed or passed. Now if I make an ajax call, I can't display the pdf in a div, and if I do it with iframe i can display the pdf in a div but can't access the information about the ckecks. what should i do?

Comment: Well you can't intercept iframe request so think of a different approach. Perhaps store something in session and use ajax to get that

Comment: thats a very good idea actually, I will try and store the information in a session object. Thanks..